# function to check if a string contains a word from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains a list of blocked words

```
+--------+------------------+
|  id    |  word            |
+--------+------------------+
|   1    |  this            |
|   2    |  word            |
|   3    |  is              |
|   4    |  blocked         |
+--------+------------------+
```

What I need to do is write a function that checks if a string contains a blocked word (word in the table) for example:

```
function blocked($string){
    if(***blocked***){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function should return `true` regardless if the word is a word on its own, or if its hidden in another word:

```
$string = "I want to see if this string is blocked"; //returns `true` because it contains 'this', 'is' and 'blocked'


$string = "iwanttoseeifthisstringisblocked"; //returns `true`
```

Hope my question is clear,

Any help appreciated

Comment: construct a performant regular expression from the table or google Boyer-Moore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this or similar database query:

```
select word from blocked_list where "you string" like concat("%", word, "%")
```

Comment: CONCAT - is function for  concatenating strings http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1):

Get the contents of the table into an array then ->

```
$comment = "iwanttoseeifthisstringisblocked";
$words = array('this','word','is','blocked');

function is_array_in_string($comment, $words)
{
    foreach ($words as $item)
    {
        if (strpos($comment, $item) !== false)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){
   if ( !( strpos($your_string, $row['word']) === false ) ){
       return true;
   };
   return false;
}
```

where `$res` is the result of executing `SELECT word FROM words`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it done in PHP you need to use the [`strstr();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function.

But you can do this using `LIKE` and `%`  in your MySQL queries